# How can I get AbsoluteExpiration DateTimeOffset of key in IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, caching, .net-core-3.1

I add a value to `IMemoryCache`

```
_cache.Set("Key", "Value", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
```

I wanna to get absolute expiration value of this key in other methods.

Or

I wanna to update value of this key without changing expiration.

How can i do that?

> In `IMemoryCache` document doesn't have any way to get it (at least i didn't see), I handle it by caching expiration. Is there any better solution for handle it?

Answer (score 1):

`IMemoryCache` (as in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)) doesn't have any method to get item expiration.
Same for its default implementation [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).